# When I try to use a VBA function that I've defined in an Excel spreadsheet, I get "That is not a valid function"

Tags: vba, excel

I defined a function in VBA as follows

```
Public Function Distance(X, Y) as Double
```

Then in a cell I try to use the function. I type "@Dis" and get the drop down menu, select the function and then enter the parameters ending up with @Distance(A1, A2) in the cell.

When I press Enter I get the Error "That function is not valid".

I enabled macros throughout the system, tried saving it as the old format and as the macro enabled workbook format to no avail.

What's wrong with my usage of this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
=Distance(A1, A2)
```

Instead of

```
@Distance(A1, A2)
```

I've never seen `@` as the correct character to call a function in Excel.

I tried the following in Excel, and it works like a charm:

> In Module1:

```
Public Function Distance(X as Double, Y as Double) as Double
    Distance = 10
End Function
```

> In a cell:

```
=Distance(A1, A2)
```

Which produces the result:

> 10

as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You'll also need to make sure that the VBA code for your function is in a **Module** and not in the code area of the Worksheet.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do not use reserved words as the names of your functions.  I tried one name Parse() and it kicked it back until I renamed it ParseString().

Comment: This was my case, the other answers didn't help.